# Maven exclude only certain files when deploying

Tags: maven

Is there a way to exclude files only when calling `mvn deploy` but have the files included when I call `mvn install`?

**EDIT:**
When I run the jar locally I want the `logback.xml` in `src/main/resources` but when I deploy it so it's a library the `logback.xml` should not be included.

Comment: Could you please explain the use case for this?

Comment: The edit has my use case

Comment: Can you put the logback.xml file in src/test/resources instead?  Plugins like jetty-maven-plugin may be configured to include the test classpath when running.

Comment: I'm running a script to execute on the jar, so that would not work

Answer (score 0):

It is not the "Maven Way" to have an artifact with different content depending on where it's stored.  Maven expects `artifact-1.0.jar` to be exactly the same in the remote repository and any local repositories.

You could have the project create a classified jar alongside the real jar.  The classified jar would include the logback.xml.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <!-- default-jar is the ID assigned to the jar:jar execution included automatically by
         Maven.  -->
    <execution>
      <id>default-jar</id>
      <configuration>
        <!-- not exactly sure of the exact syntax for excludes in the jar plugin -->
        <excludes>
          <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-with-logging</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>logging</classifier>  <!-- or whatever -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

This will create two artifacts, artifact-1.0.jar and artifact-1.0-logging.jar.  Both artifacts will end up in both repositories.  If you don't want the logging version to be attached (Maven terminology for published to repos), investigate using the `maven-assembly-plugin` which can create packages in various formats without attaching them.

You could also move the logback.xml into a separate project, package it separately, and add it to the classpath only when you run the jar from the local script.